# No CPU/ABI system image available for this target on Android-studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk

I'm trying to create an Android AVD with "Google API's (Google INC) - Api Level 21" (or 22) as the target. I always get the error message "No CPU/ABI system image available for this target". I've installed and reinstalled every package under "Android 5.0.1(API 21)" and "Android 5.1.1 (API 22)" and it still won't work. I've make sure that I didn't have two Android studio installations, and I'm also running every command i should with root privileges. Why aren't the images showing up?
Thanks.

[all the installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoBUA.png)

[error showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL51X.png)